# SSRS 2008 Stored Procedure not returning correct recordset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I create areport in VS 2008 and try to use this stored procedure it appears I get only one record that looks like from insert command.  What I want to get back is record from #WIP

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF


DECLARE @BeginDate datetime 
DECLARE @EndDate datetime --- Make sure month no 12 
Declare @NextMonth INT
set @NextMonth = @Month + 1  --- Make sure month no 12
set @BeginDate = convert(datetime, convert(varchar(4),@Year) + right('00' + convert(varchar(2),@Month),2) + '01' ) ;
set @EndDate = convert(datetime, convert(varchar(4),@Year) +  right('00' + convert(varchar(2),@NextMonth),2) + '01' ) ;

DECLARE @OwnerName nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @Value numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @Hours numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @Expenses numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @Discount numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @InvoceTotal numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @Progress numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @ActualBilled numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
Create Table #WIP (
    OwnerName varchar(50)
    ,BeginWIP numeric(18,2) 
    ,EndingWIP numeric(18,2)            
    ,PeriodAll numeric(18,2)            
    ,PeriodCurent numeric(18,2)             
    ,UnnatachedTime numeric(18,2) 
    ,Progress numeric(18,2) 
    ,Discount numeric(18,2)             
    ,NewHours numeric(18,2) 
    ,FeesStandard numeric(18,2) 
    ,ActualBill numeric(18,2) 
    ,Expenses numeric(18,2) 
    ,TotalInvoice numeric(18,2)             
    ,Real numeric(18,2) )   
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR 
    FOR
            select a.owneridname 
            ,Sum(ISNULL(t1.tcpm_hoursentered,0))  as hrs ,SUM(t1.tcpm_billingatstandardrate) as Standardbilled
            ,SUM(t1.tcpm_ActualBilledAmount) as ActualBilled
            ,SUM(t1.tcpm_actualbilledamount) as Invoicetotal
            from Filteredtcpm_timeItemValue t1
                    inner join Filteredtcpm_businessperiod b on t1.tcpm_businessperiodid = b.tcpm_businessperiodid
                    inner join FilteredSalesOrder s  on t1.tcpm_projectid = s.salesorderid
                    inner join FilteredAccount a on s.accountid = a.accountid and a.statecode=0
                    where b.tcpm_startdate >= @BeginDate 
                        and t1.tcpm_lastwipaction not in ('267120007','267120008','267120009') and  t1.tcpm_hoursentered IS not null
                group by a.owneridname      

    --OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @OwnerName,@Hours,@Value,@ActualBilled,@InvoceTotal

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
        IF EXISTS(select 1 from #WIP  where OwnerName = @OwnerName)
         BEGIN
            UPDATE #WIP 
            SET PeriodCurent=ISNULL(@Value,0)
            ,NewHours= @Hours
            ,ActualBill=@ActualBilled
            ,TotalInvoice=@InvoceTotal
             WHERE OwnerName = @OwnerName
         END
        IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from #WIP  where OwnerName = @OwnerName)
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #WIP (OwnerName ,NewHours,ActualBill,TotalInvoice,PeriodCurent) 
                VALUES(@OwnerName,@Hours,@ActualBilled,@InvoceTotal,ISNULL(@Value,01)) 
         END         
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @OwnerName,@Hours,@Value,@ActualBilled,@InvoceTotal
    END     
select OwnerName ,BeginWIP,NewHours,ActualBill,TotalInvoice,PeriodCurent,UnnatachedTime  From #WIP
```

END

Comment: On SQL Server 2008 you should use the **MERGE** command instead of a row-by-agonizing-row cursor!

Comment: Not only can he use a `MERGE`, but if I'm reading this right that RBAR cursor is only checking for existence and inserting or updating to the most recent value...just wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lone FETCH NEXT with no into at the top of your while loop.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
```

It is creating a result set for every other row in your cursor. Comment it out and I think you will get what you want.

Also because of the extra fetch, you are only processing every other row of the cursor. If that was you intent, then you will need to add an into to the fetch and push thoes values into variables.

Comment: Thanks, I stared at that all day and never saw that.